# Proof regarding the dimension of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-equations

> Fix a $2\times 2$ real matrix $A$. Let $V$ be the set of all $2\times 2$ real matrices $X$ such that $AX=XA$. Show that $V$ is a vector space of dimension of at least 2.

I'm struggling to see a good way to approach this problem. There's the brute force style method of algebraically manipulating 4 equations in 8 unknowns to show that there are (at least) two matrices $X$ that satisfy $AX=XA$ for any given $A$, but it seems like there should be a more insightful approach. Certainly the identity is in $V$, so there's one element in a basis. And the zero matrix is also in $V$, but this doesn't contribute to a basis as the columns are linearly dependent. And since we don't know that $A$ is invertible, we can't simply take $X=A^{-1}$.

Comment: How do you get 8 unknowns?

Comment: @JackLee Arbitrary matrix $A$, arbitrary matrix $X$. Both $2\times2$, so $4$ unknowns each.

Comment: Show 3 things: (1) If $X_1,X_2\in V$ then $X_1+X_2\in V$. (2) If $X\in V$ and $\alpha$ is a scalar, then $\alpha X\in V$. (3) $A,I\in V$.

Comment: But $A$ is fixed -- it's part of the information given with the problem. The unknowns are the possible $X$'s that commute with $A$.

Comment: @amsmath Oh, duh, of course $A$ itself is in $V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

- Showing that it's a vector space should be easy enough without actually considering the entries of the matrices.
- To see that the dimension is at least $2$, consider two cases:

  - What if $A$ is a multiple of the identity matrix?
  - What if $A$ isn't a multiple of the identity matrix?

Comment: So if $A$ isn't a multiple, then $\{A,I\}$ is a basis, QED. But when $A$ is a multiple, $X$ can be anything that isn't a multiple of the identity, and $\{A,X\}$ is a basis, QED. Yeah?

Comment: @Atsina You got it. Except in both cases, you can't really say that it's a basis, because the dimension can be larger. It's simply a linearly independent set contained in $V$.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. Those are basis elements, but there could be more. Thanks!

Comment: @Atsina You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

We can consider the following cases

- $A=0$ then X can be any matrix
- $A\neq 0$ singular then $X$ can be $kI$ and $kA$
- $A=kI$ then X can be any matrix
- $A\neq kI$ not singular then $X$ can be $kI$ and $kA$

Comment: Your first and second case are special cases of 3rd and 4th case, respectively. Singularity is not important here.

Comment: @amsmath Yes you are right but while I was thinking about it I didn't realized that!